# Why is FlatList renderItem prop not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

For some reason flatlist items are not rendering when I call 
`renderItem={({ item }) => {this.renderPost(item);}}` but do render when I directly use return `renderItem={({ item }) => {return(<View><Text>Hello</Text></View>);}}`. The function renderPost is the same as that return statement so I don't understand why its producing different results. I also tested and verified that the renderPost is being called by putting a console.log statement inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be calling `return` from `renderItem`. Should look like either:

```
renderItem={({ item }) => {return this.renderPost(item);}}
```

Or:

```
renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderPost(item)}
```

Comment: Adding a "return" in front did the trick. Why is it in that 2nd option you gave there is no need for a return statement? Does react native automatically add it if you don't surround the function with curly brackets?

Comment: Arrow functions without curly braces treat the expression as an implicit return value. Nothing to do with react-native, this is Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions